# Change class and variable when change radio button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help. I have input radio and main block.
How I can add value to variable javascript?

```
label first
input(type="radio" name='name' data-value='first' checked).select
label second
input(type="radio" name='name' data-value='second').select

.block
```

And how I can check is this radio checked? if checked function can't work.
My flag doesn't work.
And how can I know the first value after load document?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.select').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('checked')) {
            className = $(this).data('value');
        }
    });

    addBlock(className);
    select();
});

function select() {
    $('.select').click(function() {

        if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {

            className = $(this).data('value');
            addBlock(className);
            console.log('click');
        }
    });
}

function addBlock(a) {
    $('.block').html('<div class="' + a + '"></div>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The className variable should be declared outside of the JQuery selection. You shouldn't create global variables.